# Jquery Mobile checkbox click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

i have used code below on check box click.
It works on local host but it not worked in mobile when i unchecked check box
any one have solution for this?

```
$("#checkbox-1a").change (function(){
    var chkstatus = $(this).attr('checked'); 
    alert(chkstatus);
    if (chkstatus != 'checked') {
        $('#locationdiv').slideUp();
        $('#address').val('');
        $('#zip').val('');
    } else {
        $('#locationdiv').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Because jQuery mobile uses all that fancy markup, you need to call a special jQuery mobile function to update the check box.

```
$("#id").prop("checked", true/false).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

Works just fine. I think there are other ways to set the property, but make sure to include the refresh, otherwise jQm doesn't update the markup.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector?